# Creating docker-machine using Docker Desktop

Tags: docker

I am trying to create swarm using docker machine that consists of 3 managers and 3 workers. It works fine with Docker toolbox. However, it is failing when I tried to do the same with Docker Desktop

https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/swarm-mode/beginner-tutorial/swarm-node-vbox-setup.sh

```
PS C:\Users\admin> docker-machine create                                                                                               
docker-machine : The term 'docker-machine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.      
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.                              
At line:1 char:1                                                                                                                       
+ docker-machine create                                                                                                                
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                       
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker-machine:String) [], CommandNotFoundException                                     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I think in docker desktop you need to `docker swarm init` and to register the swarm. After this, `docker swarm join...` The docs -> 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/

Comment: A couple things; `docker-machine` doesn't exist in Docker Desktop, but there are respective commands. To create a swarm, Alejandro is correct. Also, be aware that there's currently an issue with running a swarm node as manager in Docker Desktop (Windows for sure, not sure about Mac). You can create it as manager, but you can't use the manager functions. You can create as worker and upgrade it's role to manager, but it still doesn't behave properly.

Comment: ok, it seems Docker Toolbox is proven solution for these issues as I need to run POC as of now on windows